# Inherit from another class and ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two classes

`class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base; end`

`class Kitty < Animal; end`

But when I `Kitty.find_by_name('Ser Pounce')` I find that I am actually querying the `Animals` table, despite having created a `Kitty` table through a migration.

So how can I tell rails that I want `Kitty.find_by_name` to query the `Kitty` table and not the parent `Animals` table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheriting from models that inherit from ActiveRecord is a pattern for [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html). Instead of using STI (unless that's actually what you want), I would use a behavioral mixin pattern. Basically, make Animal a module and use include, so you'd have:

```
module Animal; end
```

and then

```
class Kitty < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Animal
end
```

That's probably the simplest way of keeping tables distinct per model and still keeping behavioral style OO.

Answer (score 3):

The answer really depends on what you are tying to do: Sharing functionality, single table inheritance, or multiple table inheritance.

You can override the default STI behaviour via the [abstract_class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods.html) attribute:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Any subclasses of `Animal` will then use their own tables.

There is a *slight* drawback to this method though; scopes defined on the super class don't work.  You need to define them via a class method instead.

Comment: Be aware that you'll still have to set the `table_name` of the subclass manually to get this to work without STI.

Comment: @photoionized, are you sure? I've got an application doing this at the moment and the subclasses don't need to define their tables.

Comment: You are right, I was indeed mistaken, here's my quick test to prove you are correct: https://gist.github.com/photoionized/9f224c2a0f39574e1a44c21780a88fd9